# Ubuntu 19.04 Cheese still not working

Tags: webcam, cheese

I had already checked all previous answers and suggestions related to cheese not working and integrated webcam not working but didn't find a solution which sorts my problem yet.

[image: error screenshot]
[image: Preferences window screenshot]

My device is HP TrueVision HD, is there any problem with that?

I recently had shifted to Ubuntu 18.04 from Windows 10 and I am a beginner.

This problem is still persisting after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.10.

Note: My webcam worked fine while using in Windows 10.